# Set fixed size to SWT label

Tags: java, swt

i want to set a label size to fix size.
and not change the label size acceding to it's text
how can I do it please?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ideally you'd set the width in the layout you are using.  Also, when creating the Label you can set whether you want the contents to wrap or not (i.e. expand vertically).

So here's some examples depending on the layout:

FormLayout:

```
// Add | SWT.WRAP to get label to wrap
Label testLabel = new Label (parent, SWT.LEFT);
FormData fd = new FormData();
fd.width = 50;
testLabel.setLayoutData (fd);
```

GridLayout:

```
// Add | SWT.WRAP to get label to wrap
Label testLabel = new Label (parent, SWT.LEFT);
GridData gd = new GridData ();
gd.widthHint = 50;
testLabel.setLayoutData (gd);
```

Comment: I changed this to use Canvas instead, and now I have Canvas with Image I want to put on it a button , how can I do it?